# Как выполнять скрипты при их загрузке через AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Например, у меня есть три таба (вкладки), при переходе на вкладку делается `AJAX` запрос и получается контент `HTML + JS`, который вставляется например, в `<div>` на вкладке. HTML нормально рендерится, а `JS` в таком случае не выполняется. Вопрос как исполнить `JS` код, который пришел вместе с `HTML`-разметкой как результат `AJAX`-запроса.

Comment: А с чего Вы решили что js не выполняется? Не выполняется и не работает это разные вещи.

Comment: Ну вот к примеру http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tabs/tabs.html если перейти на вкладку Ajax Tab 1 то происходит загрузка файла ajax1.htm и дальше его содержимое отображатся во вкладку. Вопрос в том, если включить в ajax1.htm скрипт например, <script>alert("test");</script> то при его загрузке он не выполнится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получать аjax'ом html не лучшая идея, но это ваше дело.

скрипты завернутые в `<script>` исполнятся сами по себе. А вот те что по ссылкам нужно выкачать и завернуть в `<script>`.

Ко всему остальному если в скриптах повешено событие на onload то они исполняться не будут.

Comment: Не в <script> завернуть, а через eval пропустить, как в jQuery.

Comment: Через eval плохо потому что потом при возникновении какой-нибудь ошибки практически невозможно ее отладить.

Comment: @abg ясен пень, что её сложно отладить, но она ведь подключаемая. Так что отладкой таких скриптов нужно заниматься отдельно. Это тоже самое, что ужать скрипт, а потом в ужатом искать ошибки.